# Cron task runs for only 1.5 min and stops

Tags: cron

The task loads PHP code that updates the price and availability of products in an online store.
After checking the database, I found that the process aborts after about 1.5 min without updating all products.
How can I extend the time?

Platform OpenCart 2.3.

A cron task: wget -q --spider https://mysite.om/index.php?route=extension/module... Is it correct?

Comment: Does the website return a response when you open it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Check the php.ini

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 300 seconds = 5 minutes

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // 0=NOLIMIT
```

But on the most shared servers this function does not work it is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I will contact the support of the hosting company... It is currently set to 36000.